# Getting the class name of a generic class in a static variable

Tags: c#-4.0

I have a generic class and I will derive about 20 different classes from it, each with a different datatype for the generic part. The Generic class will have a static field called ConfigField which identifies a field in a configuration file. I want to calculate this field by using a combination of the name of the derived class plus the name of the generic datatype that it wraps. So, example:

```
class BaseClass<T>
{
    static string ConfigField = string.format("{0}.{1}", ???, ???);
}
class DerivedInt: BaseClass<int>{}
class DerivedLong: BaseClass<long>{}
class DerivedString: BaseClass<string>{}
...
Console.WriteLn(DerivedString.ConfigField);
```

Which should result in "DerivedString.string" as result.
Or is this not possible, since it's a static field, thus it exists only in the Generic base class? If so, any other solutions?

Comment: Do you need ConfigField to be `static`?

Comment: Yes. It's a global field used by all derived objects, thus only assigned once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Derived d = new Derived();

        Console.WriteLine(d.ConfigField); // Derived.String

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

abstract class Base<T>
{
    public string ConfigField { get; private set; }

    public Base()
    {
        ConfigField = string.Format("{0}.{1}", this.GetType().Name, this.GetType().BaseType.GenericTypeArguments[0].Name);
    }

}

class Derived : Base<string>
{

}
```